Splotches on baked normal maps
Not sure why but when baking normal maps I sometimes get these strange splotches of color that are incorrect. It's not due to any modifiers because it happens with multiple models & it still happens when the modifiers are removed. 

If anyone knows the cause of these/how to fix them it would be greatly appreciated!

hello, hard to say, maybe share your object before the baking?

These are places where the low poly intersects the high poly (even with any ray extrusion used) or where the high poly self-intersects.
